# Conflict errors when rotating shapes

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dashboard that I created, which has a speedometer (as shown below). I'm using the following code on the worksheet directly (not a module - I have a mock module in place (has no code but sub and end sub)

I get object type errors and other types of conflict error from time to time. I'd like to improve the code in such a way that there wont be any errors.

The 244 in the code below is basically the angle that points the "arrow" shape at 100% and the cell range that is multiplied by it is a % value that adjusts the rotation appropriately.

Please advise. Thanks

```
'Aligns the dials on the speedometer'


 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TL Dash").Shapes.Range(Array("Group 8")).Select
  Selection.ShapeRange.Rotation = Range("B14").Value * 244
  'ActiveCell.Select'

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TL Dash").Shapes.Range(Array("Group 223")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Rotation = Range("F15").Value * 244
    'ActiveCell.Select'

     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TL Dash").Shapes.Range(Array("Group 216")).Select
     Selection.ShapeRange.Rotation = Range("J15").Value * 244
    'ActiveCell.Select'

    End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cut out the `Select` and work directly on the shapes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B14,F15,J15")) Is Nothing Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TL Dash")
            .Shapes("Group 8").Rotation = Me.Range("B14").Value * 244
            .Shapes("Group 223").Rotation = Me.Range("F15").Value * 244
            .Shapes("Group 216").Rotation = Me.Range("J15").Value * 244
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

...and add some error checking to make sure all values are numeric.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your advice. I tried your code above, but it didn't move the gauges for some reason. Could it be the last point you mentioned? Should I specify the Dim of B14, F15 and J15 as numeric?

Comment: If it works currently for you then this should also work, unless I'm misunderstanding something about your setup.

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm a little new to VBA, but your code above can also work if I directly place the code for the worksheet itself right? Instead of explicitly creating a separate module? Currently, when I say Alt+F11 to open VB, I go to my relevant worksheet and write the code their directly. I'm not sure how the Application.Intersect function works, but when I ran your code, it didnt move the needles unfortunately, which are the shapes in question.

Comment: That method is an event handler so yes it needs to go in the sheet module. I’m not sure if your shapes are on the same sheet as the input cells?  Worth noting that if your input cells change due to a formula then you should be using the Worksheet_Calculate event instead.

Comment: Hi Tim, Ye sthe refe4rnce cells are on the same worksheet. The data is on a spearate sheet that I have created pivot tables on and then a separate cell that references a cell on the pivot table

Comment: In that case the Calculate event is what you need.